# What were the specifications of Neville's first wand?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

Neville was the other potential boy whom Voldemort could have marked as his equal. however, Harry ends up with a matching wand core to Voldemort's, sparking of *priori incantum* during their duels.

What was Neville's wand's core, length and wood? Were there any similar similarities?

Comment: I seem to recall that the only reason this happens is due to the paired cores - and since Faux only gave two feathers we can infer that Neville's wand would _not_ have produced the same effect.  This doesn't answer the wand specification question though and thus is a comment...

Comment: Ahhh I had mistakenly thought Faux had given more, but those were the last two....I'm still interested in the answer though.

Comment: This will be answerable as soon as Pottermore puts out a wand specification guide. Until then, 90% of the wands seen are of unknown specifications.

Answer (score 2):

We don't (yet) know the specifications of the wand, but we DO know that Neville's first wand was one that used to belong to his father, Auror Frank Longbottom.

We know that the core was NOT the twin of Harry's/Riddle's wands (Dumbledore hinted - and Ollivander explicitly confirmed in the below quote - that Fawks only gave two feathers), therefore we know that Priori Incantatem was not possible:

> "I remember every wand I've ever sold, Mr. Potter. Every single wand. It
>   so happens that the phoenix whose tail feather is in your wand, **gave
>   another feather -- just one other.** - *"Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone", CHAPTER FIVE, DIAGON ALLEY*